# How to make jenkins job as unstable after TestNG Failures

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have configured my test scripts to run from Jenkins using TestNG XML. This xml triggers a suite of testcases from my available test suite. This xml is triggered using a batch file and configured as a build step in Jenkins.

**Issue:**

Though some of my test case is failing, jenkins job is reporting as Pass since the batch script was completed successfully.

Is there  a way to pass the Failure report back to batch file and then to Jenkins to report fail if any test case in the suite failed.

Comment: Isn't there a Jenkins plugin for TestNG? Are you using it?

Comment: Yes i guess i have installed the TestNG plugin, but i dont see any support for execution of testNG XML. I have an option to publish testNG results though.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestNG Results Plugin, https://plugins.jenkins.io/testng-plugin.

Then publish the testng result by providing appropriate path to the testng-result.xml. The job will turn yellow on failures.

[image]